# BlackBerry Playbook - display orientation

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-playbook

My game was made for portrait view in Android but for some reason whe ported to BlackBerry Playbook it puts the simulator in portrait but the game stays in landscape mode anyway of fixing this in the code?

Comment: In the xml file there is an option called autoorientation=true .. make it as false